# My Navlink active class having an issue in React-router-v6

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a navbar using React-Router v6. When we click on any `li` element the `".active"` class will be applied. Now I styled the "active" class (like adding bg-color and colors) but when I click the home list item my logo also activated as I have provided the same path for logo image and home list item.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbars.css";

function Navbars() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul className="navbar">
          <NavLink to="/">
            <img
              src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/nxt-trendz-logo-img.png"
              alt="logo-image"
              className="logo-img"
            />
          </NavLink>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/" className="navbar-link">
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/carts" className="navbar-link">
              Carts
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/products" className="navbar-link">
              Products
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary m-2">
              Logout
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbars;
```

Comment: Can you please share the CSS code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is rendering two home `"/"` path links. If you don't want the image link to receive any "active" styling then I suggest rendering it as the regular `Link` component so the `"active"` class isn't applied.

You will likely also want to render this link into a list item `li` element to keep the correct semantic HTML within the unordered list `ul`.

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<li>
  <Link to="/">
    <img
      src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/nxt-trendz-logo-img.png"
      alt="logo-image"
      className="logo-img"
    />
  </Link>
</li>
<li>
  <NavLink to="/" className="navbar-link">
    Home
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

An alternative since all the "real" `NavLink` components your code renders also have a `"navbar-link"` classname, you can scope the `"active"` classname.

Example:

```css
.navbar-link {
  ... normal NavLink rules
}

.navbar-link.active {
  ... active link rules
}
```